# Select2 allowClear click

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is there any way to run a code by clicking the X to remove the contents of a selected select2?

I've looked at the documentation but not got me very clear if there is a way to do this, I need to reset some variables by clicking the x.

[image]

**That's my code**

```
$("#cliente").select2({
      multiple: false,
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: "Digite o nome",
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: { 
          url: "endpoints/autocompletePaciente.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function (term, page) {
              return {
                  keyword: term
              };
          },
          results: function (data, page) { 
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  data[i].id = data[i].cod;
                  //data[i].value = data[i].nome;
              }
              return { results: data };
          },
      },
      createSearchChoice: function(term) {
          return { id: term, nome: term, documento: ''};
      },
      formatResult: subjectFormatResult,
      formatSelection: subjectFormatSelection,  
      escapeMarkup: function (m) { 
        return m; 
      }
  }).on("unselecting", function(e) {
      console.log("sdsdd")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery use the following.

```
$(".select2-search-choice-close").on( "click", function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: I've tried to do that way but did not work. I do not know if it's because I'm using angujar and the component is inject after the DOM